# Symfony 2.0 bundle installation

Tags: symfony

So I am a new to doctrine, but I am not able to install a bundle at all. I am following the guide, but the "error" which I am getting is very unusual.

Anyhow, I add this lines into deps file:

```
[FOSRestBundle]
    git=http://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/RestBundle
```

Then I do:

```
./bin/vendors install
```

And I get:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Your project seems to be based on a Standard Edition that includes vendors.

Try to run ./bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

So on this standard way I am not able to install it at all. Can somebody explain me what is the problem, because to me it looks like, the symfony vendors script doesnt recognize changes in deps file at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you've downloaded the Symfony2 Standard Edition from the website. The vendor install script checks to see if the vendor directories are git repositories, and if not, will throw this error. You can fix the situation in one of two ways:

1. you can either run the command that it suggests: `php bin/vendors install --reinstall`
2. or, you can remove the vendors directory, then run `php bin/vendors install`, which amounts to about the same thing

Answer (score 1):

No need to install that. Just follow the steps in the url : http://mmoreramerino.github.com/GearmanBundle/installation.html